# How to extract values between adjacent variables in a correlation matrix in R?

Tags: r, filter, matrix

I have got huge correlation matrix, but the following is just an example:

```
    set.seed(1234)

corrmat <- matrix(round (rnorm (36, 0, 0.3),2), ncol=6) 
rownames (corrmat) <- colnames (corrmat) <- c("A", "b1", "b2", "C", "L", "ctt")
diag(corrmat) <- NA 
corrmat[upper.tri (corrmat)] <- NA 
            A    b1    b2     C     L ctt
    A      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  NA
    b1   0.08    NA    NA    NA    NA  NA
    b2   0.33 -0.17    NA    NA    NA  NA
    C   -0.70 -0.27 -0.03    NA    NA  NA
    L    0.13 -0.14 -0.15 -0.13    NA  NA
    ctt  0.15 -0.30 -0.27  0.14 -0.28  NA

> melt(corrmat)

       X1  X2  value
    1    A   A    NA
    2   b1   A  0.08
    3   b2   A  0.33
    4    C   A -0.70
    5    L   A  0.13
    6  ctt   A  0.15
    7    A  b1    NA
    8   b1  b1    NA
    9   b2  b1 -0.17
    10   C  b1 -0.27
    11   L  b1 -0.14
    12 ctt  b1 -0.30
    13   A  b2    NA
    14  b1  b2    NA
    15  b2  b2    NA
    16   C  b2 -0.03
    17   L  b2 -0.15
    18 ctt  b2 -0.27
    19   A   C    NA
    20  b1   C    NA
    21  b2   C    NA
    22   C   C    NA
    23   L   C -0.13
    24 ctt   C  0.14
    25   A   L    NA
    26  b1   L    NA
    27  b2   L    NA
    28   C   L    NA
    29   L   L    NA
    30 ctt   L -0.28
    31   A ctt    NA
    32  b1 ctt    NA
    33  b2 ctt    NA
    34   C ctt    NA
    35   L ctt    NA
    36 ctt ctt    NA
```

What I am looking is correlation values between adjacent only - means that between A-b1, b1-b2,b2-C, C-L, L-ctt (in the order in column). I need to remove other values and NA. Thus expected will be:

```
        X1   X2  value
    2   b1   A   0.08
    9   b2   b1 -0.17
    16   C   b2  -0.03
    23   L   C  -0.13
    30  ctt  L  -0.28
```

Thus they are in: `A-b1-b2-C-L-ctt` order.

Is there a easy way to filter it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way using the often overlooked functions `row()` and `col()`

```
> corrmat ## my version as there was no set.seed
        A    b1    b2    C     L ctt
A      NA    NA    NA   NA    NA  NA
b1   0.03    NA    NA   NA    NA  NA
b2  -0.41 -0.02    NA   NA    NA  NA
C    0.11  0.61 -0.18   NA    NA  NA
L   -0.28 -0.28  0.39 0.01    NA  NA
ctt -0.21 -0.41 -0.55 0.34 -0.13  NA

> corrmat[row(corrmat) == col(corrmat) + 1]
[1]  0.03 -0.02 -0.18  0.01 -0.13
```

Note that we are indexing the matrix `corrmat` as a vector here, and the bit in the brackets says return elements where the row index of each element matches the column index of each element plus 1. Using `-1` would give you the superdiagonal (i.e. above the diagonal).

To put it all together:

```
out <- data.frame(X1 = rownames(corrmat)[-1],
                  X2 = head(colnames(corrmat), -1),
                  Value = corrmat[row(corrmat) == col(corrmat) + 1])

> out
   X1 X2 Value
1  b1  A  0.03
2  b2 b1 -0.02
3   C b2 -0.18
4   L  C  0.01
5 ctt  L -0.13
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way:

```
n = rownames(corrmat)
pair.table = data.frame(X1=head(n, -1), X2=tail(n, -1), value=diag(tail(corrmat, -1)))
```

Result:

```
> pair.table
  X1  X2 value
1  A  b1  0.08
2 b1  b2 -0.17
3 b2   C -0.03
4  C   L -0.13
5  L ctt -0.28
```

Comment: You're welcome. I just now edited it to an even shorter solution using `diag`.

Answer (score 3):

It's just 1 off of the diagonal of the correlation matrix.  So, all you need to do is just shift the diagonal to be that and you're set.  Remove the first row and last column and then it's just `diag`.

```
corrmat <- corrmat[-1,-ncol(corrmat)]
data.frame(X1 = rownames(corrmat), X2 = colnames(corrmat), r = diag(corrmat))
```

Comment: OK, maybe that's actually what David Robinson did in his new edit.  I just removed the unnecessary row and column first.

Answer (score 1):

My solution based which generates combinations (comb function) using row/colnames and 'looking up' the entry in the square distance matrix. SIF stands for Simple interaction file.

```
makeSIF <- function(x) {
# args - 
#    x - m*m distance or correlation matrix
# @returns data frame in SIF format 
#
    sif <- as.data.frame(t(combn(as.character(rownames(x)), 2)))
    #print(sif)
    weight <- apply(sif, 1, indexDMatFromLookup, x)
    sif2 <- data.frame(sif, weight)
    return(sif2)

}

indexDMatFromLookup <- function(lookup, x) {
    return(indexDMat(x, lookup[1], lookup[2]))
}

indexDMat <- function(x, i1,i2) {
    return(x[i1,i2])
}
```

Seeing the other answers, this is probably much slower.

edit: it's actually not too bad.

> system.time(replicate(1000, makeSIF(corrmat)))

user  system elapsed

0.976   0.000   0.975

> system.time(replicate(1000, data.frame(X1=head(n, -1), X2=tail(n, -1), value=diag(tail(corrmat, -1)))))

user  system elapsed

0.656   0.000   0.658

only a fraction of a second slower than john's method.